# Azure Event Hub - Debugging C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send) to publish the events. I have a `Logic App` attach to the event hub. I am logging the events from the server and an Azure function. Events from the server are making through the `Logic App`, but Azure function events are not making through. How would I debug the event hub and find out where exactly the events are dropping?

Comment: First thing first, I take it the function and the logic app both operate on a separate consumer group? Otherwise what you see is expected behavior.

Comment: @PeterBons not sure if I follow. How is that expected behavior. Can you elaborate it for me?

Comment: sure, see my answer..

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: yeah, I had to delete everything and re do it. Not sure what exactly was the problem but now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

For a given [consumer group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups) message will be processed only once. By default you get just one consumer group, named $Default. (You can add more, for example using the portal). A consumer group is basically a view over the message stream. Each consumer group knows its position in this stream of messages. So, if you only use the default consumer group you only can keep one position in the message stream. And since consumers place locks on the partitions they are reading I suspect the Logic App has the locks and prevents the function from getting messages.

The solution is to create separate consumer groups for both the logic app and the azure function.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---configuration) on how to specify the consumer group to use for the azure function using the `consumerGroup` property in the function.json file.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#add-an-event-hubs-trigger) on how to set the consumer group in the Logic App trigger.